# Error to install numpy in python 3.4

Tags: python, numpy

This question may be answered in other posts. If so please refer me to those.
I want to install `numpy` in `python 3.4` for `win 32`. I follow these steps:

1. I downloaded file: numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
2. In CMP in the path of c: python34\Scripts> I copy:

   ```
   pip install " C:\Users\Myname\Downloads\ numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl"  (or pip3.4.exe install ....)
   ```

It does not install `numpy`. The error includes 8 lines like:

```
File "C: Python34\lib\site-package\pip\basecommand.py" line 215, in main status=self.run (options, args)
```

and finally

```
FileNotFoundError:[Error 2] No such file or directory: " C:\\Users\\Myname\\Downloads\\ numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl"
```

Could you please help me to figure it out?

Comment: Do you try `pip install numpy`?

Comment: @kitman0804,  no

Comment: You have a space bar character in your path, before "numpy", perhaps the error is related to that? Does the file show up when you try to "dir" it in the CMD?

Comment: @Maciek, thank you the problem was the space!!!

Comment: Cool :-) Upvote the comment then! As I am new to Stack, I wonder what will happen :P

Comment: I do not know how to vote for a comment I always do that for question. If you know please let me know! Thanks

Comment: @Maciek why don't you just write an answer based on your comment?

Comment: OK, here it is!

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

`pip install " C:\Users\Myname\Downloads\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl"`

(without the space character before 'numpy')